# Thread behaviour on member variable lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

When running the below code, it throws IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
class Consumer {
    private int capacity = 5;
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(capacity);

    class ConsumerWaitNotify implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                consumeItem();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        void consumeItem() {
            try {
                synchronized (queue) {            //Line 1
                    while(queue.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.format("%n%s: Waiting..Empty Queue, Size: %d%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                                            queue.size());
                        wait();           //Line 2
                    }
                    int popItem = queue.poll();
                    System.out.format("%n%s: Consumes Item: %d, Size: %d", Thread.currentThread().getName(), 
                                        popItem, queue.size());
                    notify();
                }           
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConsWaitNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer pc = new Consumer();
        Consumer.ConsumerWaitNotify cwn = pc.new ConsumerWaitNotify();
        Thread consumer = new Thread(cwn, "CONSUMER");
        consumer.start();

    }
}
```

Below is the ERROR:

```
CONSUMER: Waiting..Empty Queue, Size: 0
Exception in thread "CONSUMER" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.threadconcurrency.lock.prodcons.Consumer$ConsumerWaitNotify.consumeItem(ConsWaitNotify.java:67)
    at com.threadconcurrency.lock.prodcons.Consumer$ConsumerWaitNotify.run(ConsWaitNotify.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

While debugging I found that, when line 2 i.e. wait() command is executed then thread instead going out of runnable state, it jumps to Line 1 for execution, and it executes it two times. Hence it throws the exception.

What I assume is that after *wait*, thread may have release the lock of object (*queue*) but still holds the object of class *ConsumerWaitNotify*, and that's why it behaves like that.

I have achieved what I want by making a separate class of *Consumer* with method *consumeItem()* having *synchronised(this)* code and *ConsumerWaitNotify* with Consumer object as member.

But what's wrong in this. I am still confused and not able to predict the exact behavior. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are synchronizing on variable `queue` but call `wait()` and `notify()` on the `this` object. You either need to hold the lock with `synchornized(this)` or call `queue.wait()` and `queue.notify()` to ensure that you notify the same monitor you have the lock for. You can take a look at [Guarded Blocks docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Do note that you don't need to implement the queue yourself. JDK provides a few [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

Comment: Thanks. I know about _Linked and Array Blocking Queue_ that make work easier but just to understand wait and notify I wrote that. One query was that, I assume that since code _synchronized(queue)_ is called on object _queue_, it will automatically wait on that i.e. there will a implicit call like _queue.wait()_ and _queue.notify()_. I think the implicit call is still _this.wait()_ i.e. on object of class  ConsumerWaitNotify. So there must be explicit call on wait and notify. Is am I correct ?

Comment: @Nizam yes, `synchronized` doesn't change the scope for `wait` and `notify` methods.